# Transfer from multiple 'accounts' not multiple 'subindices'

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, sub-address, transfer, account

Using the GUI wallet and the RPC wallet it is possible to create a transfer across sub-indices of the same account.

But the [subaddress documentation](https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/) indicates that it should be possible to create a transfer across multiple accounts in the same wallet:

> Thus, a single transaction can - in
> principle - aggregate and spend outputs from multiple addresses (and
> by extension from multiple accounts). *The CLI or GUI wallet may not
> directly support creating such transactions for simplicity.*

I do notice that last sentence - indicating that the functionality might not be implemented.

If I look at the [RPC wallet transfer command](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) it only allows a single account index.

Is there way around this?